# Completely reset Python and start over

Tags: python, pip, package, anaconda

For a while now (now = 2023 October) I've been doing my Python development in Jupyter notebooks.

When I first started (however long ago that was) I didn't use Anaconda or Miniconda to set up environments or manage package libraries. I just installed Python to the default folder and used `pip install` commands to get whatever libraries I needed for whatever I was doing.

I'd like to clean up all of the Python-related stuff on my computer and restart with Anaconda so that I can do the management properly this time.

Some poking around says that uninstalling Python won't do anything about pip and its libraries. The converse may also be true.

I know just enough about working with the command line to get myself in trouble most of the time. Here's what I found as recommendations for uninstalling pip and packages.

- Store Pip packages
  --python -m pip freeze > requirements.txt
  --pip freeze > to_remove.txt
- Uninstall all packages
  --pip uninstall -y -r <(pip freeze)
  --pip uninstall -y -r <(pip freeze)
  --pip freeze > requirements.txt && pip uninstall -r requirements.txt -y
  --python -m pip uninstall -r requirements.txt
  --pip uninstall -y -r <(pip freeze)
- Reinstall
  --pip install -r to_remove.txt

I'm using 64 bit Windows 10. So what's the best way to completely wipe Python, pip, packages, and anything else related (except maybe my noteooks) from my computer so that I can install Anaconda and start fresh?

Comment: I applaud this effort. Python (at least in past versions, maybe the current ones are better) has been notorious for getting it's tentacles into a system. Now, if you plan to do this frequently, having a disposable/renewable virtual machine is the way to go. If you are using VMware (even the free edition), you can setup a new VM and just zip the whole thing up for reuse later.